# Background Image Too Large

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my background image always 100% width, but it's not working. With my current code, I get the picture where I want it, but there's a bunch of unwanted dead space (all the yellow background below pic). Overflow options don't fix this.

If I leave out the fixed height/width, then the image takes on 0x0 size for some reason; if I use `background-size: cover`, the image becomes too large, and no longer sits well in my parent container

**jsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/CSS_Apprentice/z7bojmbn/1/

```
.mainpic {
    background-image: url('http://www.placehold.it/1922x1080');
    width: 1922px;
    height: 1080px;
    background-size: contain;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do:

background-size: 100% 100%;

This will keep the background image stretched 100% to the size of the container it currently is in. So, if it is in the body, it will fill the whole background of the page.

Comment: Damn you answered like five seconds before i was about to post it

Comment: Haha, it things goes fast here doesn't it :p

Comment: Are you saying get rid of everything except bg-image and bg-size: 100% 100%? If so, that didn't work for me :( http://jsfiddle.net/CSS_Apprentice/z7bojmbn/2/

Comment: You would still need to set the with and height of the div, otherwise it will be so small that it wont show up.

Comment: Is there a way for me to do this using percentages? I'm trying to avoid using fixed units

Comment: @CSSApprentice http://jsfiddle.net/z7bojmbn/3/ check this you can change the 100% to any of the percentage you like

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the `cover` declaration.

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
```